# XCode 5.1 bumps lastUpgradeVersion variable in .xcscheme files

Tags: xcode, jenkins, xcode5

I have a Xcode project that I keep in a Git repository. The 3rd party stuff is included as submodules.

Everytime I open the project in Xcode 5.1 it changes a line in .xcscheme files from `LastUpgradeVersion = "0500"` to `LastUpgradeVersion = "0510"`.
The problem is that the line change is also made in submodules and therefore I get a dirty Git state that causes several problems, for example, my CI tests on Jenkins fail because Jenkins cannot checkout submodules because they are dirty.

A several ideas that might help:

1. I might prevent Xcode from bumping the variable. But how?
2. Removing all submodules after Jenkins build, but that doesn't seem right
3. Upgrade libraries that I have as submodules, but that involves some huge refactoring risk if the libraries have changed a lot

What is the best way to solve this situation?

Comment: Don't know about git, but SVN allows to mark files as excluded/ignored by the checkout. All hidden files starting with `.` should be marked as ignored.

Comment: Hi ULazdins, did you finally found a solution?

Comment: @user23 - can't remember how I fixed this. The issue was with XCode 5.1 is it still relevant with more recent XCode versions?

Comment: It is not giving me problems still, but sometimes I see it changing (XCode 10.1) and I was investigating to prevent any issue. Thnks!